# android activity recreation- will the intent contain original extras?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an activity that expects to be passed a few extras when launched.

When this activity is destroyed and recreated, will the intent returned by `getIntent()` called from within `onCreate()` contain the same extras that were present when the activity was originally launched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on if it was intentionally destroyed.  If it was destroyed by a finish() call, no.  If it was destroyed because the system was freeing up memory, yes. It will also have a flag stating that this is a recreate (useful if your app only works from the first activity, such as an app that needs you to be logged in).

Comment: If my activity implements onSaveInstanceState() and saves some state, can I just do a null-check on the savedInstanceState parameter to onCreate() to determine if it's being called due to an initial creation or a recreate-after-destroy?

Comment: if((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0)  will return true if it was launched from the history (a recreate and destroy).